# Dynamic position of dropdown/modal in React ( similar to modals on facebook from where you can report the posts )

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I looked through the facebook page and inspected the option-list that comes up when you click on the options in right hand corner of a post and found out that it was like a modal/dropdown and clicking out will exit the modal/dropdown .This modal is positioned dynamically depending on the position of the post on the screen such that the list appears just below the button(or above depending whether whole list would be visible or not) using transform : translate. I want to achieve this in my web app in React. I tried making it but couldn't figure out how to make it disappear when clicked outside .[Link to an image of the modal/dropdown on facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tO6b5.png)

```
<span className="post-actions">
        <img
          className="more-options-button"
          src={more}
          onClick={togglePostActions}
        />
        <div
          className="post-actions-list"
          style={showPostActions ? null : { display: "none" }}
        >
          <p onClick={toggleReportPost}>Report Post</p>
          
            <p
              onClick={() => {
                props.deletePost(props.postId);
              }}
            >
              Delete Post
            </p>
          
        </div>
      </span>
```

Comment: Post your code. How are we supposed to know by just seeing your image what you're doing wrong? Also, that looks like a customized dropdown than a modal to me.

Comment: yes its more of a dropdown but it can't be positioned depending on the scroll height  in a dropdown so I referred to it as a modal

Comment: You can listen on the click of the document and if the event.target is not from your modal you can remove it.

Comment: it would be sufficient but i need it to be visible at all times (when scrolled it should appear above the button)